# Proof if $a \vec v = 0$ then $a = 0$ or $\vec v = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm kicking myself over this one, but I just can't seem to make the argument rigorous. From Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*:

for a vector space $V$ with an underlying field $F$:

Take an element $a$ from $F$ and $\vec{v}$ from $V$. $a\vec{v}=\vec{0}\implies a=0 $ or $ \vec{v}=\vec{0}$

After only being able to come up with half of a direct proof, I tried doing this by proving the contrapositive $a\neq 0 \wedge \vec{v} \neq \vec{0} \implies a\vec{v}\neq \vec{0}$

Say $a\vec{v}=\vec{u}$.
Since $a$ is non-zero, we can divide both sides by $a$.

$$\vec{v}=\frac 1 a \vec{u}$$

If $\vec{u}$ were $\vec{0}$ then by

$$\frac 1 a \vec{0}=\frac 1 a (\vec{0}+\vec{0})\implies\frac 1 a \vec{0}=\vec{0}$$
$v$ would be $0$ as well. Since it isn't by assumption, $\frac 1 a \vec{u}$ cannot be zero and so $\vec{u}$ cannot be as well.

1. Is this fully rigorous? It seems like a very simple question, but I'm not sure about it. Namely, the last step of $\frac 1 a \vec{u}\neq 0 \implies \vec{u}\neq 0$ doesn't seem obvious. I think I need to use the $1\vec{v}=\vec{v}$ axiom, but I'm not sure how.
2. Is there a more direct proof? This whole contrapositive business seems a bit clunky for something so simple.

Comment: If $a \neq 0$, then multiply by $\frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: I got that half easily, what I didn't get was the other half: that in this situation $\vec{v}\neq 0 \implies a=0$. Or is that the whole proof for reasons I'm not getting?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - I can't see what you mean.

Comment: @RobertMastragostino You see that $a\neq 0\implies \vec v=\vec 0$. It follows that $\vec v\neq \vec 0\implies a=0$ (this is the contrapositive).

Comment: and of course I manage to miss that and somehow use a contrapositive anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $a\in F,\vec v\in V$ and suppose $a\vec v=0$. If $a\neq 0$, then $a^{-1}\in F$ so 
$$\vec v=(a^{-1}a)\vec v=a^{-1}(a\vec v)=a^{-1}\vec 0=\vec 0$$
thus either $a=0$ or $\vec v=0$.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to prove that "P or Q" holds, it is often useful to assume that one of the conditions fails, from which it may follow readily that the other *must* hold (which proves the statement).

In this case, we know that non-0 field elements have multiplicative inverses, and can show easily that scalar multiples of the zero vector will again be the zero vector. Then if we assume $a\neq 0$, it readily follows that $v=0$.

Comment: So we are saying $\bar p \implies q$ is sufficient to show that $p \cup q$ holds? But how is this guaranteeing that $\bar q \implies p$ holds?

Comment: @RishiNandhaVanchi it is both necessary *and* sufficient. That is, "$p$ or $q,$" "$q$ if not $p,$" and "$p$ if not $q$" are equivalent statements, which is a good exercise to prove.

Answer (score 2):

We can also show the contrapositive: If $a \neq 0$ and $v \neq 0$ implies $av \neq   0.$

Assume $a\neq 0$ and $v \neq 0.$ Let $V$ has dimension $n,$ and express $v$ in terms of the standard basis vectors: $$v = v_1 e_1 + \ldots + v_n e_n.$$ Then by our assumption that $v \neq 0$ and by the definition of linear independence, at least one of the $v_i$'s is non-zero. Now, multiply $v$ by $a$ to get $$av = (av_1) e_1 + \ldots + (av_n) e_n.$$ But since $a \neq 0,$ at least one of the $av_i$'s will be non-zero, and hence the non-zero linear combination $$(av_1) e_1 + \ldots + (av_n) e_n$$ cannot equal to the $0$ vector. So, $av \neq 0.$

Comment: I like this, but doesn't it jump the gun a bit? Dimension, basis vectors, and linear independence seem a bit more complicated than the solution. It looks (naively) like it's working backwards.

Comment: @RobertMastragostino I agree. I was thinking of a way to avoid arguing about the inverse (of course $V$ is defined over a field $F$, but still..)

Comment: We can't suppose $ V $ is a finite dimensional space.

Answer (score -1):

first try to prove av≠0 if both $a\ne0$ and $v\ne0$
given: $a\ne0$ and $v\ne0$
so, assume $av=0$
in next step divide both sides by $a$ to get $v=0$ which is a contradiction. So $av≠0$ if both a and v are not zero.

Now, make three cases $a=0 , v=0 , (a=0\  \&\ v=0)$,
use ($0V=0$ where $0$ in left is scaler) and ($a0=0$ where $0$ in left is vector).